# Selected item populating in Select tag using JSTL?

Tags: java, html, jsp, drop-down-menu, jstl

I store Birthday Month in database as value using following code in JSP.

```
<select name="birthday_month" id="birthday_month">
  <option value="-1">Month</option>
  <option value="1">Jan</option>
  <option value="2">Feb</option>
  ...
</select>
```

Output code in JSP to show previously selected item using JSTL that I am using (which is not correct)

```
<select name="birthday_month" id="birthday_month">
  <c:forEach var="value" items="${birthdaymonth}">
    <option value="${birthdaymonth}">${birthdaymonth}</option>
    <option value="1">Jan</option>
    <option value="2">Feb</option>
    ...
  </c:forEach>
</select>
```

`What I am getting from this code is value like 1 or 2 in select tag`

Other Information:

1. I store birthday month as value like 1,2,3.. for Jan,Feb,Mar... in Database
2. I bring value of birthday month in request scope in Servlet using
    `request.setAttribute("birthdaymonth", user.getBirthdayMonth());`

What i was expecting

1. When i show later JSP it should show previously stored birthday month as Jan,Feb, Mar and not 1,2,3 and also show other Option values including selected item as highlighted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To dynamically iterate over a collection of months, you'd like to store the months in a `Map<Integer, String>` where the key is the month number and the value is the month name. To make a HTML `<option>` element by default selected, you need to set the `selected` attribute.

So, assuming that you have a `Map<Integer, String> months` and a `Integer selectedMonth` in the scope, then the following should do:

```xml
<select name="birthday_month">
    <c:forEach items="${months}" var="month">
        <option value="${month.key}" ${month.key == selectedMonth ? 'selected' : ''}>${month.value}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

The conditional operator `?:` will print `selected` when the `selectedMonth` is equal to the currently iterated month number.

Comment: This is working. But, when I click drop down arrow for Option Value, the Option value means months are not in order i.e they are in order like this `Mar,Feb,Oct,Jan,Jul,Jun,May,Apr,Sep,Aug,Nov,Dec`. Why is this happening? Any reason?

Comment: Use `LinkedHashMap` instead of `HashMap`. Then the elements will be maintained by insertion order instead of by hashcode.