# selecting an option in a dropdown list using request parameters

Tags: html, jsp

I'm kind of new to this so please bear with me. 
I have a value from the db which needs to set the currently selected value in a dropdown .this is passed to the front end as a request parameter. I tried using selected="parameter" attribute with the select tag but doesnt seem to work. I also tried value="", no result. 
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to serve the jsp with a selected value in the `<select>`, put the `selected` attribute in the corresponding `option`.

```
<select id="dropdown">
  <option value="1">option 1</option>
  <option value="2" selected>option 2</option>
  <option value="3">option 3</option>
</select>
```

Use the JSTL tag `<c:if>` to test for equality between the request parameter and the current value. For instance, with a request parameter named `selectValue`:

```
<option 
    <c:if test='${param.selectValue == currentOption}'> selected </c:if>
>
</option
```

Take a look at the following question for details: [Selected item populating in Select tag using JSTL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6090146/851811)

To elaborate on the matter, in case you're building your options dinamically (`<c:forEach>`), while looping the options, output `selected` in the `<option>` when the current `<option>`'s value is equal to the request parameter (code untested):

```
<select id="dropdown">
    <c:forEach var="item" items="${list}">
        <option value="<c:out value='${item}' />"
            <c:if test="${param.selectValue == item})"> selected </c:if>  >
            <c:out value="${item}" />
        </option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

In case the options are static, you could add something like this in each `<option>` (code untested):

```
  <option value="1" 
    <c:if test="${param.selectValue == 1})"> selected </c:if> >
    option 1 
  </option>
  <option value="2" 
    <c:if test="${param.selectValue == 2})"> selected </c:if> >
    option 2
  </option>
```

If you want to set the selected value through javascript, use for instance

```
document.getElementById("dropdown").value = <c:out value='${param.selectValue}'/>
```

Comment: I need to set the selected option from the request parameter. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: I tried your code for the case where the options are static . seems to be not working . any ideas why?

Comment: @DaTaBomB I've updated the answer. You have to use `<c:if test="${param.selectValue == '1'})">`. This is [JSTL basics](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL.html).

Comment: See @BalusC 's suggestion for a cleaner/simpler way of doing this, using only [Expression Language](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html). At least, using JSTL is still better than scriptlets ;)

Answer (score 6):

To the point, you need to set the `selected` attribute **only** whenever the submitted value matches the selected value. Cleanest would be to use the conditional operator `?:` in EL for this as using JSTL `<c:if>` would end up in clumsy and hard-to-read code.

Here's an example:

```
<select name="foo">
    <option value="1" ${param.foo == '1' ? 'selected' : ''}>One</option>
    <option value="2" ${param.foo == '2' ? 'selected' : ''}>Two</option>
    <option value="3" ${param.foo == '3' ? 'selected' : ''}>Three</option>
</select>
```

Please note that the `foo` in `${param.foo}` must exactly match name of  `<select name="foo">`. Please also note that the `${param.foo}` value must exactly match the value of `<option value>`. The usage of `id` as suggested in other answer is irrelevant here. It's only relevant for the client side. IDs aren't used as request parameter names or values at all.

Comment: +1 Good to learn a nicer way to do this. My jsp skills are getting rusty.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with javascript and jquery. 
After the page was rendered you simply update the select box and set the value provided in a param.
See the following jsp/jquery example:

```
<select id="dropdown">
  <option value="1">option 1</option>
  <option value="2">option 2</option>
  <option value="3">option 3</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   // set select options with jquery and EL
   $("#dropdown").val("${param.foo}");
});
</script>
```

In a JSF/Facelets page you can use this EL syntax (replace ${} with #{})

```
$("#dropdown").val("#{param.foo}");
```